# MPI debugging with VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mpi, visual-studio-debugging

The cluster debugging option is removed from Visual studio 2012. 
So is there any way to debug MPI apps in VS2012 ?

Comment: A workaround I found goes like this: Start debugging using mpiexec.exe  to spawn processes and attach to your app's process. Extensions like [ReAttach](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8cccc206-b9de-42ef-8f5a-160ad0f017ae)  help ease the pain.

Comment: can you give full steps how to do it ?

Comment: Use mpiexec to spawn multiple versions of your app -> mpiexec -n 2 myapp.exe Then use VS attach to process to start debugging different processes. ReAttach enables reattaching to the previously attach process with a button.

Comment: Thanks @tunc, you just saved me an awful lot of pain. +1

Comment: @tunc, if this answers your question, you should write your own answer and then accept it so others will be able to find it easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual studio 2012 and later versions do not support MPI debugging. However there is a workaround:

Start debugging by specifying mpiexec.exe as your command and related parameters and the name of your executable as command arguments:

```
Command-> mpiexec.exe
CommandArguments-> -n 2 myapp.exe
```

When the execution starts, use Debug->Attach to process... to attach the debugger to one your processes. Sometimes I add a simple press any key to continue logic to my app, just to pause the program until I finish this attaching process.
In order to ease tings you can use an extension called [Reattach](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8cccc206-b9de-42ef-8f5a-160ad0f017ae) that lets you attach to the last processed you attached with one button click.

One problem with this workaround is that you cannot select which MPI process you attach :(