# Is there a way to debug MPI program in visual studio 2019 on windows?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, mpi

I'm using MPI from Microsoft implementation on VisualStudio 2019 on windows. I was looking for a way to debug my program without pain.

Comment: Does this help https://www.cac.cornell.edu/slantz/CATS/MPI_Cluster_Debugger_for_Windows.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following doc, it's written for VS2010 but should still works today. You will need to install Microsoft HPC Pack.

[Walkthrough: Launching the MPI Cluster Debugger in Visual Studio 2010](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ee441265(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Edit:
According to this post: [MPI debugging with VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682843/mpi-debugging-with-vs2012), MPI debugging was removed as of VS2012, so the doc only applies to VS2010.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35789170)